# Dropbox search method fails to search

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, dropbox, dropbox-api

I am using "dropbox-sdk" gem to upload the files in DropBox account. I used the following method to search.

```
require "dropbox_sdk"
client = DropboxClient.new("ACCESS_TOKEN")
client.search("/", "myfile.ipa")
=> [{"rev"=>"86009",
  "thumb_exists"=>false,
  "path"=>"/App/myfile.ipa",
  "is_dir"=>false,
  "client_mtime"=>"Mon, 08 Sep 2014 18:59:17 +0000",
  "icon"=>"page_white",
  "bytes"=>5050139,
  "modified"=>"Tue, 09 Sep 2014 17:55:05 +0000",
  "size"=>"4.8 MB",
  "root"=>"dropbox",
  "mime_type"=>"application/octet-stream",
  "revision"=>79144}]

client.search("/", "myfile.ipa")
=> []
```

i was able to get the response at first time. If i again search with the same file name, it returns with the empty response.

Any idea?

Comment: Cross-linking with the GitHub issue: https://github.com/dropbox/dropbox-sdk-ruby/issues/8

Comment: Seems like a Dropbox bug. We're looking into it.

Comment: Is the file name and metadata here edited by any chance? This bug may be specific to certain parameters, so it would be good to know exactly what you saw this with. If you want to share privately, you can open a ticket here: https://www.dropbox.com/developers/contact

Comment: @Greg No i didn't edit the file name and metadata.

Comment: We just pushed a change for this. Please try this again and open a ticket with more details if the issue isn't resolved for you: https://www.dropbox.com/developers/contact